# Не с прилагательными в полной форме - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> Лица, не( )годные к военной службе

Полагаю, здесь раздельное написание.

Comment: Посмотрите примеры в словаре «Управление...» на сайте Грамота.ру: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Негодный&all=x

Comment: Меня смущают их ответы. Потому что они пишут, что раздельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае НЕ пишется раздельно: ***Лица, не годные к военной службе.***

Пояснение

1. ***Негодный*** – интересное слово, впрочем, не единственное в этом роде. В словаре даются два его значения: (1) непригодный для каких-то целей и (2) некачественный. Обратим внимание на то, что в первом случае требуется зависимое слово (сильное управление), а во втором такой необходимости уже нет.  Тем не менее **слитное написание**  «негодный к военной службе» возможно и именно оно обычно применяется, так как такая семантика регулируется словарем.
2. Но в нашем случае оборот **обособлен**, и у Розенталя есть материал на эту тему, где приводится пример со словом «несвойственный».

Там такая же ситуация, то есть значение определяется по отношению к чему-либо.  В правиле четко указано, что при обособлении определительного оборота **НЕ пишется раздельно** – в этом случае  прилагательное  (в постпозиции по отношению к определяемому слову) получает дополнительную предикацию и в большей степени проявляет признак по действию, чем качественный признак.

3. **Я бы еще объяснила эту тему так.** Считается, что пояснительные слова (кроме усилительных) обычно не влияют на написание НЕ с прилагательными.  Но все-таки **частные случаи** возможны, если НЕ относится не к прилагательному, а **ко всему  словосочетанию**. Здесь показателен такой пример, в котором раздельное написание НЕ очевидно и обязательно: *Она была бледна, но не (болезненно бледна).*

В примере с обособленным оборотом такой обязательности нет, но в правилах рекомендуется раздельное написание НЕ.  Принимая такое решение, мы также отрицаем словосочетание: ***годный к военной службе – не (годный к военной службе)***.

**Справочный материал по теме**

**1. Из словаря:**

**НЕГОДНЫЙ**,  1. Такой, который нельзя употребить на что-л., использовать для чего-л.; непригодный. Н. проект. Эта обувь негодна для бега. Никуда не годен (совершенно непригоден). 2. Плохой, не соответствующий по качеству, свойствам. Н-ая верёвка. Выпускать негодную продукцию. 3. Разг. Дурной, скверный. Н. мальчишка. <Негодность, -и; ж. Н. к военной службе.

Управление в русском языке

**НЕГОДНЫЙ** для чего / к чему / на что. Полковой врач... был признан негодным для строевой службы (Кар.); Негодная к употреблению пища; Негодные на это дело материалы. См. годный.

**НЕСВОЙСТВЕННЫЙ,**  кому-чему или для кого-чего. Такой, который не составляет чьё-л. свойство. Рассказал всё с несвойственной ему откровенностью.

**2. Розенталь:**  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

8. **Раздельное написание** частицы НЕ с прилагательным, имеющим при себе **пояснительные слова**, встречается: 3) при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами после определяемого существительного (иногда): предприятия, не подведомственные тресту (**при обособлении** конструкция с прилагательным приближается по значению к причастному обороту); ср.: *Шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле. — Это черты, **не свойственные** нашей молодёжи.*

Comment: Хорошо, понятно, убедительно.

Comment: Единственное, у меня несостыковка (п. 2) с "...в этом случае прилагательное (в препозиции по отношению к определяемому слову)..." У нас же не в препозиции.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено (как обычно: хочу сказать, что белое, а пишу, что черное). Я бы не придавала  позиции прилагательного  существенного влияния, здесь (как я думаю) важнее обособление оборота для слова, требующего для себя зависимых слов.  Тематика примеров у Розенталя вполне определенная. В этом случае просматривается сходство с причастием, зависимые слова как бы переходят от глагола к прилагательному (как и для причастия): не годится для службы - не годный для службы. Но раздельное написание НЕ только при обособлении и дополнительном предикативном значении.

Comment: После ваших объяснений всё становится простым и понятным. )))

Answer (score 0):

Пишется слитно. Раздельное написание было бы в случае противопоставления: "Не годный, а плохой". В данном случае слово "негодный" является качественной характеристикой.